# AWS SNS Message format using Boto3

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-ses

I have set up an SNS notification and can successfully send a list into the message as follows:

```
sns.publish(TopicArn='arn:aws:sns:eu-xxx-x:1234567:my_sns', Message=f"New URLS are {newUrls}")
```

This gives the following output in the SNS message:

New URLS are ['http://www.123.bar', 'http://abc.foo', 'http://foo.bar']

**How do I structure the output to look like this with new lines and no square brackets for the list:**
(this is a trivial task in Python but I am struggling to do this with the message parameter)

New URLS are:

http://www.123.bar

http://abc.foo

http://foo.bar

I have tried sending a print function into the message parameter but it returns `None`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I resolved it:

```
newUrlsString = "\n".join(newUrls)

nl = "\n"

sns.publish(TopicArn='arn:aws:sns:eu-xxx-x:1234567:my_sns', Message=f"New URLS are: {nl+newUrlsString}")
```